# Pass parameters to web api controller with jQuery data attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I have this jQuery call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:5832/api/Login/Post",
            data: JSON.stringify({ username: 'user12', password: '1234' }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
```

Which calls this web api controller action:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string username, string password)
{
    string authenticationToken = "";
    authenticationToken = hpl.LoginUser(username, password);
    //Some other code

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, authenticationToken);
}
```

I'm trying to submit the parameters with the data attribute but the call is not triggered.

When I'm changing the url to: 
http://localhost:5832/api/Login/Post?username=1&password=2

I'm able to reach the controller action.

How I can pass the parameters as part of the data attribute of the jquery call instead of query string params?

Comment: Just use: `data: { username: "user12", password: "1234" },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net Web API does not support multiple parameters inside the body of the request.

You can only send one single parameter using the `FromBody` attribute, so instead of multiple parameters just use a single object which contains any property you need:

```
public class LoginModel {
    public string username { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }
}

[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] LoginModel loginModel)
{
    string authenticationToken = "";
    authenticationToken = hpl.LoginUser(loginModel.username, loginModel.password);
    //Some other code

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, authenticationToken);
}
```

As an aside: `AcceptVerbs("POST")` and `HttpPost` attributes are redundant, use one of them but not both.